# Replace javascript swich statement

Tags: javascript

I have a switch in javascript that I need to put it different.
How can I write this in a better way to avoid the switch?

```
var types = {   
    Int: 2,
    Short: 3,
    Long: 4,
    Double: 5,  
    Decimal: 6, 
    String: 1,
    Guid: 10,
    Variant: 11,               
};

switch (data.columnTypeId) {

    case types.String:
    case types.Guid:
    case types.Variant:
        self.GetStrings(data);
        break;

    case types.Int:
    case types.Decimal:
    case types.Short:
    case types.Long:                        
    case types.Double:  
        self.GetNumbers(data);
        break;

    default:
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? It looks great to me.

Comment: A whole bunch of `if`s?  Maybe if you explained *why* you need to replace perfectly fine code...

Comment: I don't want to repeat the different cases in the switch

Comment: I don't see any undue repetition in your code. It's very readable.

Comment: It's perfectly functional, it's clear and understandable and rather less complicated than using an `if`/`else` (or `if`/`else if`/`else`). Why do you dislike the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about doing the same map, but map a function reference instead?

```
var columnTypes = { 
    2: self.GetNumbers,
    3: self.GetNumbers,
    4: self.GetNumbers,
    5: self.GetNumbers,  
    6: self.GetNumbers, 
    1: self.GetStrings,
    10: self.GetStrings,
    11: self.GetStrings,
    0: self.GetDefault //Guessing the default value would be 0          
};

columnTypes[data.columnTypeId](data);
```

or with a safe check:

```
if (columnTypes.indexOf(data.columnTypeId) !== -1) {
    columnTypes[data.columnTypeId](data);
} else {
    self.GetDefault(data);
}
```

Or as @dandavis pointed out in a comment:

```
columnTypes[data.columnTypeId || self.getDefault](data);
```

Comment: You've lost the `default` action (which, admittedly, isn't shown in the question, but the `default` case is specified).

Comment: Good catch. Would be good to know what the default case would be.

Comment: `columnTypes[data.columnTypeId || self.getDefault](data);`

Comment: the problem with this is that each function needs a parameter data

Comment: the data parameter will work exactly as in your code.

Comment: I see now, the data parameter

Comment: No Problem! Glad to help :)